# how to use the return value of function grep in R

Tags: r

I want to use the return value of function grep, I just want to judge whether the var_name has the var I want:

```
> res<-grep(y,var_name,fixed=FALSE)
> res
integer(0)
> (res==integer(0))
logical(0)
> (res==NULL)
logical(0)
```

But it is always logical(0), is there any way I can solve this problem

Comment: Could you make it reproducible?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the result'? true/false? the match string? the position in a list of possible matches? If you show us more context for your code, you can probably vectorize this with `grep()`/`match()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
if(length(res)==0)
{
    # some code
}
```

Or directly:

```
grepl(y, var_name)
```

Example:

```
y='dog'
var_name='I am a cat'
# grepl(y, var_name)
#[1] FALSE
```